# Android Studio: Get data from XML and store it in a list

Tags: arrays, xml, android-studio, arraylist, xml-parsing

I have an XML with the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 one
 two
 three
 four
 five
 six
 seven
 eight
 nine
 ten
</resources>
```

How do I store that data in an arrayList or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the type of your data (looks like a bunch of strings to me). Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="numberstrings">
       <item>one</item>
       <item>two</item>
       ...
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Put the data in a file called "strings" (or so) in your res/values folder. Access the data like so:

```
String[] numberStrings = activity.getResources.getStringArray(R.array.numberstrings);
```

If you have to, you can then transform the array to a List like so:

```
List<String> numberStringList = Arrays.asList(numberStrings);
```